# Serve file in byte[] as URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, server, arrays

I am working on a serverside component of a webapp which should display images stored in database.

I am trying to find a way to transform a byte array or a stream to a valid URL for the HTML img tag.

The byte[] contains the entire file including headers.

I have searched for a solution but I kept finding the reverse problem of saving to filestream from a url.

Is there a way to serve the file via some kind of a dynamically generated url or do I have to create a physical copy of the file to link to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the Byte Array to a Base64 image.

```
    public string getBase64Image(byte[] myImage)
    {
        if (myImage!= null)
        {
            return "data:image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(myImage);
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Your image tag will look like this: `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA...">`

Or for larger images (and other file types) it's better to use a [Generic Handler](http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx)

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //check if the querystring 'id' exists
        if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
            string idnr = context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();

            //check if the id falls withing length parameters
            if (idnr.Length > 0 && idnr.Length < 40)
            {
                //get the data from the db or other source
                byte[] bin = getMyDataFromDB();

                //clear the headers
                context.Response.ClearHeaders();
                context.Response.ClearContent();
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.Buffer = true;

                //if you do not want the images to be cached by the browser remove these 3 lines
                context.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
                context.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);
                context.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);

                //set the content type and headers
                context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myImage.jpg\"");
                context.Response.AddHeader("content-Length", bin.Length.ToString());

                //write the byte array
                context.Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);

                //cleanup
                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
```

Your image tag will look like this: `<img src="/Handler1.ashx?id=AB-1234">`

Comment: I had no idea that you could actually embed the image itself in the src tag!
I will try this right away.

Comment: Note that converting to Base64 will create a big string. I usually dont use the first method with images larger than 50 kb.

Comment: @VDWWD No need to create a ashx handler: your code serving image as byte[] (second solution) would work in a Page_Load() of a "normal" getimage.aspx page - just replace `context.` with `this.` (or nothing)

Comment: I need to do this with a PDF so I guess I'll try this method but it's going to be more like Meg instead of 50K. Do you have any other suggestions to offer. Thanks, Mike